# Disable form validation on empty forms with Play Framework

Tags: forms, validation, playframework

I'm pretty new to Play Framework.

My problem is that when a user clicks on the register link, he will instantly see validation errors.

The problem is that the method that serves the form also validates the form. So when the user clicks on the register link, gets to the validation without any input and then gets validation errors.

One solution would be to have an extra method to only serve the register form. But this would require an extra form and an extra route.

Another solution would be to disable validation on empty forms.

Is this possible? If not is there an other way?

Comment: Why would the second method require an extra form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the way to a good solution. Make a second method.

```
GET  /register controllers.RegistrationController.showRegistration()
POST /register controllers.RegistrationController.register()
```

The first is to display the registration page with the form, the latter to handle the form submit.

A method should stick to do one thing: either to show a registration page or to handle a post. Generally it's not a good idea to write a single method with a lots of if-then-else flow control statements.

Play framework also supports REST principles: in a simplified way `GET` is to retrieve a resource (=an empty registration page here), `POST` is to submit data(=do the registration).

Have a good look at Play framework's [examples](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples), I think the computer-database is very simple and a good starting point for you.

Comment: Ah, i missed the point with GET and POST. Thanks for the explanation :)